# Checking sums with condition in R

Tags: r

I need to check the sums in some dataframe. But its elements do not sum up because some of them contain other. In this example 051040 is a part of 051043. Although most elements ends with "0", those which last digit is 3 always bigger or equal to counterparts with last digit 0. In other words I need to find all elements ends with "3" and skip those counterparts with "0". In this example 051040 and 051050 must be skipped because of 051043 and 051053 presence. Note that element "05000" is a control sum, obviously it also must be skipped. So I need to find the difference:
05000 - SUM ("051010", "051043", "051053", "052020", "052100", "052220", "052310") = 0
Something like that.
Here is an artificial example (actual dataframe is really big).

```
Area <- c("050000", "051010", "051040", "051043", "051050", "051053", "052020", "052100", "052220", "052310")
Total <- c(100,  28,  16,  22,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10)
sodf <- data.frame(Area, Total)
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: could you indicate your expected departure

Comment: I need to find is number in "Total" of element "050000" (i.e 100) equal to sum other elements except 051040 and 051050.

Comment: You could try `sum(sodf[-c(1, which(diff(as.numeric(x)) == 3)),"Total"]) == sodf$Total[1]`

Comment: @Donald Seinen The problem is that "Area" is character. Also, I can not apply to (x).

Comment: @Pavlo oops out of habit I put `x` instead of `sodf$Area`. Is there a problem with converting to numeric? The difference should still be 3 if there are only variations ending in 0 or 3, regardless if the trailing 0 gets dropped. An alternative approach could be a regex but that would be a bit more involved. In that case I'd recommend adding the *regex* tag to your post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the substrings.

```
sodf[with(sodf, ave(substring(Area, 6) == 3, substr(Area, 1, 5), FUN=\(x) {
  if (any(x)) x else TRUE
})), ] |>
  (\(x) x[1, 2] - sum(x[-1, 2]))()
# [1] 0
```

In an `lapply` for multiple areas, I expanded slightly your `sodf` to demonstrate (not exactly sure however, how your area codes exactly look like, but first two digits seem relevant).

```
lapply(split(sodf, substr(sodf$Area, 1, 2)), \(x) {
  x <- x[ave(substring(Area, 6) == 3, substr(Area, 1, 5), FUN=\(x) {
    if (any(x)) x else TRUE
  }), ]
  x[1, 2] - sum(x[-1, 2])
})
# $`05`
# [1] 0
# 
# $`06`
# [1] 111
```

---

*Data:*

```
sodf <- structure(list(Area = c("050000", "051010", "051040", "051043", 
"051050", "051053", "052020", "052100", "052220", "052310", "060000", 
"061010", "061040", "061043", "061050", "061053", "062020", "062100", 
"062220", "062310"), Total = c(100, 28, 16, 22, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 211, 28, 16, 22, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yours answer truly amazed me. You can really see "behind the scene". The first two digits are the determinants of higher territory level. And actually, there are 2 dozen of them. But it's a long story because we have a lot of other variables. So the data frames are big enough and no need to combine them in a single data frame. I and my partners decided to process this data separately. So in one data frame, the first two digits are the same. I hope I will use your wonderful suggestion in other works too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One row solution can be this:

```
sum(sodf[!sodf$Area %in% stringr::str_replace_all(sodf[!grepl('0$',sodf$Area),"Area"],'[1-9]$','0') & !sodf$Area %in% sodf[grepl('^[0]+[1-9]{1}[0]+$',sodf$Area),"Area"] ,"Total"])
```

How does it work ?

1. You find rows with Area that does not end with 0.
   `sodf[!grepl('0$',sodf$Area),"Area"]` # "051043" "051053"
2. You find how this row should end, if they had a 0. I used a function from stringr package. `stringr::str_replace_all(sodf[!grepl('0$',sodf$Area),"Area"],'[1-9]$','0')` # "051040" "051050"
3. You find rows that are not included in group 2 and does not have '050000' structure *(^[0]+[1-9]{1}[0]+$)*, then sum their total. `sum(sodf[!sodf$Area %in% stringr::str_replace_all(sodf[!grepl('0$',sodf$Area),"Area"],'[1-9]$','0') & !sodf$Area %in% sodf[grepl('^[0]+[1-9]{1}[0]+$',sodf$Area),"Area"] ,"Total"] )` # 100

Same result can be achived splitting the code in multiple lines with dplyr package.

Comment: Yours code works correct. I've got the sum of area units. I think I'll be able to find the difference between the whole territory and small units. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague suggested the following variant.

```
library(tidyverse)
check_diff <- function(df) {
   # Find value Total, for instance ends with 0000
   sum_control <- df |>
       filter(str_detect(Area, "0{4}$")) |>
       select(Total)

   # Find second number from the end where the last character is 3 and connect them into one string
   before_last_3 <- df |>
       filter(str_detect(Area, "3$")) |>
       pull(Area) |>
       str_sub(-2, -2) |>
       str_flatten()

   # Create string for filter pattern
   filter3 <- str_c("[", before_last_3, "]0$")

   # filter data on new conditions and find sum
   sum <- df |>
       filter(!str_detect(Area, "0{4}$"),
              !str_detect(Area, filter3)) |>
       summarise(sum(Total))

   sum_control - sum
}
```